# CSS remove empty space by translate

Tags: css

The expected result should be that the `.item` ( green color ) is followed by any element like `p` without any empty space like below:
[image]

I was trying to do this by `translateY`, but it just move the div `.item` going up and left an empty white space like the below:

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;  /* For illustratoin purpose only to see the result */
  padding: 30px;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - 30px)); /* Here is my try */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <p>Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
</div>
```

I have also tried `margin-top: -50%;`, I thought it should work but it just going up which I think is not "50%", going so much more than -50% although I don't know why like below.

**Edited:** negative margin will only work if I know exactly what's its height, say its height is 200px, then I can do `margin-top: -100px;`. But now the height of `.item` is unknown/flexible where the `height: 200px;` in the code is just for illustration purposes.

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;  /* For illustratoin purpose only to see the result */
  padding: 30px;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: calc(-50% - 30px); /* Here is my try */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <p>Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Negative margin should work. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Dobxgm

Comment: @Paulie_D Nope, it not gonna work. I have edited my question to explain this.

Comment: @doqgmui should the `.item` be exactly offset by *half* its own *"unknown"* height?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah, that's right. That's the ideal design/result.

Comment: @doqgmui in such case - I've added a possible suggestion/solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of, is to
create a *white background* `::before` pseudo element inside of your *Item* element, that way you can position it at **top 50%** but most importantly at **height 50%** - making that height actually relative to the *Item*'s height:

```css
/* QuickReset */
*, ::before, ::after  {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Just to visualize */
*, ::before, ::after {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

.card {
  --padd: 30px;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: var(--padd) 0;
}

.card-item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3de821;
  margin: 0 var(--padd);
}

.card-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% + (var(--padd) * 2));
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(var(--padd) * -1);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card-desc {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: var(--padd);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-item" style="height:140px;">140px height</div>
  <div class="card-desc">
    Hello.<br>Scroll down.....
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-item" style="height:250px;">250px height</div>
  <div class="card-desc">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla a optio magni. Neque sed repellendus fugiat. Earum necessitatibus deleniti consectetur sequi, nemo iure, omnis molestias minima culpa ipsa rem nam.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-item" style="height:60px;">60px height</div>
  <div class="card-desc">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla a optio magni. Neque sed repellendus fugiat. Earum necessitatibus deleniti consectetur sequi, nemo iure, omnis molestias minima culpa ipsa rem nam.
  </div>
```

the reason for this solution being: `margin` cannot relate to the element height, and `translate` cannot act on sibling elements positions.

Answer (score -2):

Use another nested div:

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - 30px));
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <p>Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is still white space after the `p` element, also the green is not going outside by 50% of its height. Checkout the expected result from the image in the question.

Answer (score -2):

you can also use position absolute.

```css
  .main {
            background-color: gray;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 150px;  /* For illustratoin purpose only to see the result */
            padding: 30px;
          }
          
          .item {
            background-color: green;
            height: 300px;

            width: 70%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
          }
```

```html
  <div class="main">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <p>Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Like I said the height of the `.item` ( green ) is unknown/flexible. It will cover the `p` element if its hight reaches a certain level. Try to change the height of the `.item` to like 500px, you will see what I mean.